# Why doesn't this Elasticsearch query return any results?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here are my mappings for index `metadata`

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "metric": {
            "properties": {
                'model_id': {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"}
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

I can see that I have 1 document in Kibana under that index
[image]

Here is my query as a curl command:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/metadata/metric/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "term" : {
                    "model_id" : "2532070e-da4b-465f-ba3b-f96beaaa6d5c"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Here is what it returns:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

I followed the directions in the documentation here to try and get this working:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not querying the right type, you query `metrics` instead of `metric`, this should get you what you want:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/metadata/metric/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
                                         ^
                                         |
                                   remove s here
```

Comment: I had actually setup my index incorrectly. You are correct here, but it was just a typo in my stackoverflow post. I went back and confirmed I was using metric

Comment: Gotcha, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your index is setup correctly.

Comment: You should probably explain a bit more what you had wrong if you want your answer to be helpful to people :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ES 5.6.2 , try this mapping

```
"mappings":{
  "metric":{
     "properties":{
        "model_id":{
           "type":"string",
           "index":"not_analyzed",
           "fields":{
              "keyword":{
                 "type":"keyword",
                 "ignore_above":256
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

}